# How to prevent duplicate identifier issue when declaring namespaces in typescript 1.8?

Tags: typescript, typescript1.8

I am trying to generate declaration files for the openUI5 framework.

They use a Namespace called jQuery, so I declared it in my jQuery.d.ts file as root element:

```
declare namespace jQuery {
   ... content ...
}
```

Now I would like to use the jquery declaration files together with my declarations. Though, I get a the conflict with the defined jQuery variable in the jquery.d.ts file:

`declare var jQuery: JQueryStatic;`

Here are the error messages:

> Error TS2300  Duplicate identifier 'jQuery'.  Step 9 -
> Component [...]\typings\jquery\jquery.d.ts
>
> Error TS2300  Duplicate identifier 'jQuery'.  Step 9 -
> Component [...]\typings\ui5\jQuery.d.ts

Is there any way to make my jQuery namespace to coexist with the jquery variable declaration?

Would it would be possible to use a different name during design time and then replace that name when generating the javascript output?

Comment: What module system and target are you using?

Comment: Target is ES5. What do you mean by module system? Here is a sample project: https://github.com/apazureck/openui5TypescriptGenerator/tree/master/Walkthrough/Step%205%20-%20Controllers